# Vue-storefront installation error. Can't build storefront npm

Tags: magento, vue.js, storefront, vue-storefront

I have some questions according to the installation of Vue-storefront on my local.
I am using Mac OS 10.13.4 and node version 8.11.5, npm version 5.6
But while building storefront npm, it returns an error.

```
 [Error: Can't build storefront npm.                                                                                │
│     at Promise (/Volumes/Works/web/vue/vuestorefront/vue-storefront/core/scripts/installer.js:412:16)             │
│     at new Promise (<anonymous>)                                                                                  │
│     at Storefront.npmBuild (/Volumes/Works/web/vue/vuestorefront/vue-storefront/core/scripts/installer.js:408:12) │
│     at <anonymous>                                                                                                │
│                                                                                                                   │
│ Please check log file for details: /Volumes/Works/web/vue/vuestorefront/vue-storefront/var/log/install.log][1]
```

Why this happens?

Comment: [Your answer is in the documentation](https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront/blob/master/doc/FAQ%20and%20Receipes.md#how-to-prevent-error-cant-build-storefront-npm). Have you tried this yet?

Answer (score 2):

As in
https://docs.vuestorefront.io/guide/basics/recipes.html#how-to-prevent-an-error-can%E2%80%99t-build-storefront-npm

> The error "Can't build storefront npm" appears because npm can't automatically install required modules. To prevent this error, you should manually install those modules before running the installer. It's easy:

```
git clone https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront.git vue-storefront && cd vue-storefront
npm install
npm install vue-carousel vue-no-ssr
npm run build # check if no errors
npm run installer
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the yarn.lock file which locks certain version of dependencies. Try these steps:

1. delete the *yarn.lock* file
2. delete the *node_modules* folder
3. run `yarn`
   (so the dependencies are downloaded again - you will see a lot of
   warnings which is not bad, although your project will not be future
   proof)
4. run `yarn installer` again